# Flask and url rewrite

Tags: python, nginx, flask, url-rewriting, uwsgi

Is it possible to do url rewrite with Flask under Nginx+uWSGI?
I need to add SEO links, so pages of Flask website should be available with two links, for example:
`/post/3` and `/2014_10_08_post_title`.
Connections between normal link and SEO link should be stored in database.
What is the easist way to do it? Is it better and faster way to do it within Flask app or it can be done within nginx?
Thanks!

Comment: Do it in flask.. It is clearly the easiest way to handle your problem, using nginx sould lake a crazy idea to me.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please help me with routing? How can it be done:
1) we know SEO url, we know the url it relates
2) how to find out and load necessary endpoint with necessary args without redirecting? because redirect in Flask changes result url, and we need to keep SEO url.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Flask allows routing multiple URLs to the same view:

```
@route('/post/<post_id>', defaults={'seo_url': None})
@route('/<seo_url>', defaults={'post_id': None})
def view(post_id, seo_url):
  if post_id:
    ...
  elif seo_url:
    ...
```